# Indentation in align-environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align, gap

How do i get a symmetric separation of this equation:

[image]

I don´t want to have this gap in front of the first less than or equal sign. I currently use an align-environment, but I´m not sure if this is the best way to do it.

A minimal example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm, mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter\betr{\lvert}{\rvert}
\newcommand{\E}[1]{\mathbb{E}\left[{#1}\right]} %Expectation
\newcommand{\bet}[3]{\beta^{{#1}}_{{#2}}({#3})}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
        &\E{\betr{D_x\bet{n}{k}{\mathcal{P}_n}}^4}& \leq 16\E{\left[\mathcal{P}_n(B_{r_n}(x))\right]^{4(k+1)}}& \leq 16\E{\left[Poi(r_*f^*)\right]^{4(k+1)}}, \\
        &\E{\betr{D_x\bet{n}{k}{\mathcal{X}_n}}^4}& \leq 16\E{\left[\mathcal{X}_n(B_{r_n}(x))\right]^{4(k+1)}}& \leq 16\E{\left[Bin\left(n,\frac{r_*f^*}{n}\right)\right]^{4(k+1)}}.
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Unrelated look up `\DeclareMathOperator` to define `\Poi` and `\Bin`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm, mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter\betr{\lvert}{\rvert}
\newcommand{\E}[1]{\mathbb{E}\left[{#1}\right]} %Expectation
\newcommand{\bet}[3]{\beta^{{#1}}_{{#2}}({#3})}

\begin{document}
    \begin{alignat*}{2}
        \E{\betr{D_x\bet{n}{k}{\mathcal{P}_n}}^4}& \leq 16\E{\left[\mathcal{P}_n(B_{r_n}(x))\right]^{4(k+1)}}&&\leq 16\E{\left[Poi(r_*f^*)\right]^{4(k+1)}}, \\
        \E{\betr{D_x\bet{n}{k}{\mathcal{X}_n}}^4}& \leq 16\E{\left[\mathcal{X}_n(B_{r_n}(x))\right]^{4(k+1)}}&& \leq 16\E{\left[Bin\left(n,\frac{r_*f^*}{n}\right)\right]^{4(k+1)}}.
    \end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

[image]